# Definition of Java's CMS GC log lines?

Tags: java, content-management-system, jvm, garbage-collection, verbosegc

Examining a Java runtime with CMS (Concurrent-Mark-Sweep) GC enabled, **what is the definition of the `CMS` space in the logs below?**  Shall I assume it is the tenured space?  I see the following lines of a minor-major-minor GC event

```
23.481: [GC 23.481: [DefNew: 1051K->128K(1152K), 0.0029912 secs] 11925K->11027K(13600K), 0.0031697 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
23.492: [Full GC 23.492: [CMS: 10899K->9379K(12448K), 0.2675281 secs] 11182K->9379K(13600K), [CMS Perm : 16383K->16359K(16384K)], 0.2686291 secs] [Times: user=0.25 sys=0.00, real=0.27 secs]
23.956: [GC 23.956: [DefNew: 4224K->49K(4736K), 0.0027654 secs] 13603K->9428K(20372K), 0.0029230 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]
```

In particular the `[CMS: 10899K->9379K(12448K), 0.2675281 secs]` at the `23.492` event.  Does this display the *tenured* space just labeled as CMS?  Is CMS only performed on tenured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: not a JVM memory expert ;)

If I believe [Understanding CMS GC Logs](http://web.archive.org/web/20170819080128/https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/understanding-cms-gc-logs), this kind of log shows a drop in the CMS **generation space occupancy**, which is about tenured generation space.

It may be linked with [Occupancy Fraction](http://web.archive.org/web/20131213032943/https://blogs.oracle.com/bharath/entry/taming_gc_for_sip_applications), which plays a critical role in controlling things happen in old generation.

> Having a lower bound on this value allows the CMS to run frequently and keep the old generation in check all the time.

Comment: Just for reference, interesting GC settings here: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5413878